# Sinatra Heroku PostgreSQL connection bad

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra

I get "connection bad" when I try to connect to my PostgreSQL database from my Sinatra application. I'm using Heroku to deploy the app and my workstation is currently Windows. i tried, still same error message:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

From the log:

```
PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

From config/enviironments.rb:

```
db = URI.parse(ENV["DATABASE_URL"] || "postgres://localhost")

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
  :host => db.host,
  :username => db.user,
  :password => db.password,
  :database => db.path[1..-1],
  :encoding => 'utf8'
)
```

This is the main app.rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'sass/plugin/rack'
require 'pony'
require 'active_record'
require 'pg'
require 'postgresql'
require './vars.rb'
require './includes/functions'
require './config/environments'
Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
use Sass::Plugin::Rack
set :haml, :format => :html5
get '/admin' do
  admin_haml :'admin/index'
end
get '/admin/users' do
  admin_haml :'admin/users'
end
```

This is the function to test PostgreSQL:

```
def dbdeb
conn = PG.connect :user => "postgres"
  output = conn.server_version
  conn.close
  return output
end
```

This is the gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'
gem 'sinatra', '1.1.0'
gem 'haml', '4.0.7'
gem 'sass', '3.4.20'
gem 'activerecord','4.2.5'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord'
gem 'pg'
gem 'postgresql'
gem 'pony','1.11'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well you ARE calling `PG.connect :host => "localhost"` in your `dbdeb` method, but the Posgres-Server is not on **localhost** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you do not have a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable defined for your Heroku app.

Try running the following command to see what environment variables are set on your Heroku app:

```
$ heroku config
```

This should list what variables are available. As you will see, there is no `DATABASE_URL` variable set.

To set this variable, you need to create a Heroku Postgres database:

```
$ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-basic
```

This will create two environment variables in your Heroku app:

- `DATABASE_URL`
- `HEROKU_POSTGRES_COLOR`

You can find more about this in the Heroku postgres docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#create-a-new-database

Comment: i did as you told me but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Do you see a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable listed when you run `heroku config` on the command line?

Comment: yes, i do see the DATABASE variable and still have same error message. @rdegges

Comment: In this case, there is likely some other code in your ruby app which is connecting exclusively to localhost. The error you're receiving shows that you're trying to connect to localhost, which implies that your DATABASE_URL variable is not being used properly. I'd look at the code for something like that.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is the environments.rb or the functions.rb that causes the error. but I don't what to change.

Comment: i did'nt mean i dont want change my code, i did mean i dont know what i need to change. i am sorry i was'nt clear enough. anyway i solved my problem myself. i forgot to run rake db:create_migration. i will accept your answer as you helped me with problem, I had forgotten to run your command too. anyway thanks very much for your help! @rdegges